# Parse Android SDK get ArrayList and return it

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm stuck, I try to get an Array in Parse. I succeed to get it however I can't return it to use it in another method.

Do someone know what should I do ?

Retrieved ["international","entrepreneurship"]

```
public class CardsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
String test = currentUser.getObjectId();


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cards);

    // Specify which class to query
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
    query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("tastes"));
    // Specify the object id

    query.getInBackground(test, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {

                    ArrayList<String> userTastesGot = (ArrayList<String>) object.get("tastes");

                    Log.d("User", "Retrieved " + userTastesGot);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(CardsActivity.this, "Nous n'avons pas trouvés vos goûts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

    });
```

Comment: What do you plan to do with the data? Do you plan to update a view?

Comment: I plan to use this listArray in another method to select randomly one of the elements inside (for instance 'entrepreneurship') this will not be displayed in a view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return it from `onCreate`, no.  I wouldn't even retrieve it in `onCreate` unless you can be certain that it won't be needed until it has been retrieved.  I would do something like this:

```
interface Callback<T> {

    void success(T result);
    void failure(Exception error);
}

void getUserTastes(Callback<ArrayList<String>> callback){

// Note the special way to get a query for the user table
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("tastes"));
// TODO: Specify the object id

query.getInBackground(test, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
    public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                ArrayList<String> userTastesGot = (ArrayList<String>) object.get("tastes");

                Log.d("User", "Retrieved " + userTastesGot);

                callback.success(userTastesGot);

            } else {
                callback.failure(e);
            }
        }

});

}
```

Use whatever protection levels are appropriate.

Comment: Thanks however how I call this method ? Do I call it in onCreate method ?

Comment: Call it from wherever you need to have the results.